# Collection View confuses minimum line spacing and minimim interitem spacing under iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I just ran into a very strange issue regarding the behavior of a `UICollectionView` and I think both the collection view and I are pretty confused.

I had implemented a particular collection view with a *horizontal* scroll direction in our project and soon after quality assurance issued a bug ticket saying that the spacing between the collection view items was not correct on some device. I inspected the bug further and realized that the problem did not only persist on that particular device but generally on all devices running iOS 9. **On iOS 10 everything worked as expected.**

So I created a simple sample project to isolate the underlying issue that can be found on GitHub:

#### [Interactive Sample Project that shows the problem](https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/Collection-View-Line-Spacing-Experiment)

First, I was even more confused that the sample project *didn't* show the iOS 9 bug. However, as soon as I set the `estimatedItemSize` to a non-zero value in order to use self-sizing cells (i.e. Auto Layout) the same incorrect spacing occurred again.

I figured that only under these particular circumstances — **iOS 9 + `estimatedItemSize != .zero`** — the collection view actually **confuses** the `minimumLineSpacing` with the `minimumInteritemSpacing`, at least when implementing the respective flow layout delegate functions:

[`collectionView(_:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617705-collectionview)
[`collectionView(_:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617696-collectionview)

So whenever you want to specify one of these spacings you have to implement the other one.

This seems to be a serious system bug to me but it's such a big thing that I cannot believe no one else ever ran into this problem. Thus, it's more likely that *I* made some mistake in my code or in understanding how these spacings work (though it's pretty clearly described in the Apple Docs for the delegate methods linked above).

#### Why is the collection view mixing up the two dimensions?

[image: estimatedItemSize == .zero]
[image: estimatedItemSize != .zero]

*The "Use Auto Layout" switch in the sample project toggles the `estimatedItemSize` between `.zero` (disabled) and `CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)` (enabled).*